# How to Run group of Query with condition SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, conditional-statements

I was writing A SQL File containing different sections like the example below.
On running whole file
it should  run the particular section if the input value is equal to section name:

```
Def input_var=1;
--//if condition to run 1,2,3 section as per input variable
-------------Section 1-------
--begin
update table1 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
Delete table1  where status='E';
update table2 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
Delete table2  where status='E';
--end
-------------Section 2-------
--begin
update table3 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
Delete table3  where status='E';
update table4 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
Delete table4  where status='E';
--end
..... multiple section
```

Comment: Wrap all the code into PL/SQL block and use `case` statement

Answer (score 0):

You got few options. Simplest might be to just if/else it:

```
  BEGIN
    IF   ( section = 1 ) 
    THEN
      Update table1 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
      Delete table1  where status='E';
      Update table2 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
      Delete table2  where status='E';
    ELSIF( section = 2 ) 
    THEN
      Update table3 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
      Delete table3  where status='E';
      Update table4 Set status='RN' where status='IP';
      Delete table4  where status='E';
    ELSIF( section = 3 )
    THEN
      <code>
    ELSE
      <code>
    END IF;
  END;
```